# solving a trigonometric identity: $\frac{\sec^2 x + 2 \tan x}{1 + \tan x}=1+\tan x$.

Tags: trigonometry

$$\dfrac{\sec^2 x + 2 \tan x}{1 + \tan x} = 1 +\tan x$$    I started by making $1/\cos^2 x$ the

$2\tan x/\cos x$ making them but I can't came the the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the identity $$\sec^2 x = 1 + \tan^2 x$$

This gives us $$\dfrac{\sec^2 x + 2 \tan x}{1 + \tan x} = \dfrac{\overbrace{(1 + \tan^2 x )+ 2\tan x}^{(1 + \tan x)^2}}{1 + \tan x} = \dfrac{(1 + \tan x)^2}{1 + \tan x} = 1 +\tan x$$

Comment: Again a serial of -'s

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$(1+\tan x)^2=1+\tan^2x+2\tan x=\sec^2x+2\tan x$$

Divide either sides by $\displaystyle1+\tan x$